# Shiny output elements not displaying in bs4Dash with nested modules

Tags: shiny, nested, shinymodules, bs4dash

EDIT: The author of the `bs4Dash` package, David Granjon, recently provided an answer to the question asked in the Github issue referenced below and closed it.

1. My question is very likely related to [this issue in `bs4Dash` github repo](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/45), but no answer was provided there.
2. The full reproducible codes are at the end of the question

## My goal

I am making a modularized Shiny application and am attempting to do it with the `bs4Dash` package. This is what the application looks like:

**Picture 1**

[image: The app]

The end application has several sections (I only made the Introduction for this example) and each section contains at least one `bs4TabCard`. The tabcard in the picture above has one `uiOutput` and one `rhandsontableOutput` element, which are rendered in the server function. Note that these are both `***Output` elements. In the reproducible code for **Picture 1** (which you can find at the end of the question), I do not use any module. However, my goal is to use several modules because the application has the potential to become quite large. For this simple example, I try to use two modules: one module for each section (i.e. each `bs4TabItem`) and one module for each tabcard. This means that the two modules will invariably be nested: the tabcard module will be inside the section module.

**Picture 2**

[image: Show modules in the app]

## The issue

The issue is that when I implement the modules, the `***Output` elements are not displayed:

**Picture 3**

[image: Modularized app with issue]

The surprising thing is that `***Input` elements are displayed. I made a third module containing a `numericInput` only and placed it in the second tab of the tabcard. The picture below shows that the `numericInput` is displayed with no problem:

**Picture 4**

[image: Modularized app works with input elements]

## I did my homework

In this [issue](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/45), a similar problem is reported, but there has not been any solution offered and my digging around proved unsuccessful. It seems that there is a problem when an output element is placed deep inside several nested containers in `bs4Dash`.

## The reproducible code

**Reproducible code for picture 1**

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(rhandsontable)

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    old_school = FALSE,
    sidebar_min = TRUE,
    sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
    controlbar_collapsed = FALSE,
    controlbar_overlay = TRUE,
    title = "Basic Dashboard",
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(

      sidebarMenu(
        bs4Dash::menuItem(
          text = "Introduction",
          tabName = "tab-introduction",
          icon = ""
        )
      )

    ),
    controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
    footer = bs4DashFooter(),
    body = bs4DashBody(

      bs4TabItems(

        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = "tab-introduction",

          bs4TabCard(
            id = "tabcard", title = "Tab Card", side = "right",

            bs4TabPanel(
              tabName = "Tab 1",
              uiOutput("ui"),
              rHandsontableOutput("hot")
            ),

            bs4TabPanel(
              tabName = "Tab 2",
              p("Hey")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({ rhandsontable(mtcars[1:10, 1:3]) })
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      numericInput("num_ui", label = "Num In", value = 15)
    })
  }
)
```

**Reproducible code for Picture 3 and Picture 4**

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(rhandsontable)

# Tabcard module ----------------------------------------------------------

mod_tabcard_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  bs4TabCard(
    id = ns("tabcard"), title = "Tab Card", side = "right",

    bs4TabPanel(
      tabName = "Tab 1",
      uiOutput(ns("ui")),
      rHandsontableOutput(ns("hot"))
    ),

    bs4TabPanel(
      tabName = "Tab 2",
      mod_numinput_ui(ns("num"))
    )
  )

}

mod_tabcard_server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({ rhandsontable(mtcars[1:10, 1:3]) })

  output$ui <- renderUI({
    numericInput(session$ns("num_ui"), label = "Num In", value = 15)
  })

  callModule(mod_numinput_server, "num")

}


# Numeric input module ----------------------------------------------------

mod_numinput_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  numericInput(ns("num"), "Num In", 0, 0, 10)
}

mod_numinput_server <- function(input, output, server){
  return(reactive({input$num}))
}


# Section module ----------------------------------------------------------

mod_section_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  mod_tabcard_ui(id = "tabcard")

}

mod_section_server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(mod_tabcard_server, id = "tabcard")
}


# The app -----------------------------------------------------------------

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    old_school = FALSE,
    sidebar_min = TRUE,
    sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
    controlbar_collapsed = FALSE,
    controlbar_overlay = TRUE,
    title = "Basic Dashboard",
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(

      sidebarMenu(
        bs4Dash::menuItem(
          text = "Introduction",
          tabName = "tab-introduction",
          icon = ""
        )
      )

    ),
    controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
    footer = bs4DashFooter(),
    body = bs4DashBody(

      bs4TabItems(

        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = "tab-introduction",
          mod_section_ui(id = "mod")
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    callModule(mod_section_server, id = "mod")
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing a namespace in the mod_section_ui module. It should be:

```r
mod_section_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  mod_tabcard_ui(id = ns("tabcard"))
}
```